# BAPI or FM for searching FI documents

Tags: finance, sap-erp, bapi

I am searching for a BAPI to search FI documents, based on the input criteria (document type, posting date,...). Same as it is on `FB03` transaction, but the Document List screen, not the screen with only three inputs (Document Number, Company Code, Fiscal Year).

As I don't have the document number, I need the search enabled BAPI.

I am calling the function module `BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST` for posting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like 'BAPI_ACC_CO_DOCUMENT_FIND' is going to solve my problems. Still checking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to answer my own question - I was hoping to skip these two days of investigation by getting an answer here :)

BAPI_ACC_CO_DOCUMENT_FIND is correct BAPI to use for searching the posted FI documents. What I found out is that if I want to search by posting date, I have to provide Controlling Area (but instead of an error, there is nothing returned).